# Drawing strings from an array in drawrect

Tags: ios5, delegates, drawrect

I am trying to draw strings from an array in drawrect, but they are not being drawn. The drawRect code looks like this

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    CGRect ourRect;
    ourRect.origin.x=ourRect.origin.y=20.0;
    ourRect.size.width=130.0;
    ourRect.size.height= 100.0;
    CGPoint pointer;
    pointer.x=pointer.y=20;
    NSString*string;
    string=[[NSString alloc] init];

    [string drawAtPoint:pointer withFont:font];

    NSMutableArray * whatShouldIDraw=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    whatShouldIDraw=[self.dataSource whatToDraw:self];
    NSUInteger i;
    for (i=0; i<[whatShouldIDraw count]; i++) {
        [[[whatShouldIDraw objectAtIndex:i] equationBit] drawAtPoint:[[whatShouldIDraw objectAtIndex:i]drawPoint] withFont:font];
    }

}
```

The dataSource protocol is implemented in the view's controller. The objects in the array are of a class that holds a string and a point at which to draw that string. I used NSLog to make sure that the objects were actually getting put into the array properly (they are). Also, there is a line that sends setNeedsDisplay to the view. When I run this code, it comes up blank though, so I am not sure what is going wrong. This is my first attempt to make drawRect run with data that is inputted from within an application, so I imagine the problem comes from how I implemented the datasource protocol.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bad question whose answer did not lie within the code posted. The problem was that, I did not set the view controller to be the delegate. I added : `self._equationView.dataSource=self;` and problem was solved.